# Que diferença há entre objectos serializados e não serializados?

Tags: java

Sei que um objeto está serializado quando a sua classe implementa a interface *java.io.Serializable* mas, gostaria de saber o que significa o objeto estar serializado e que diferença há com um outro não serializado.

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mPfJToWysdk/UMJNP5_ut3I/AAAAAAAAAGE/Cm2nCOAxdcM/s1600/serialization.png

Answer (score 4):

[**Serialização**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) significa pegar um objeto (ou conjunto de objetos) e colocá-lo num formato apropriado para transmiti-lo em rede ou salvá-lo em arquivo. Objetos que implementam `Serializable` não *estão* serializados, eles **são capazes de** se serializar.

A princípio, é possível se serializar objetos em formato binário ou texto (XML, JSON, etc). Não sei quais formas Java suporta nativamente, mas a principal é um formato binário próprio da linguagem. A serialização é tipicamente feita através dos [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) (pra salvar um objeto numa *stream*) e [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) (para ler uma *stream* com dados serializados e "montar" de novo o objeto).

Um exemplo (salvar objetos em arquivo, depois lê-los de volta):

```
  /* Escrevendo alguns objetos num arquivo */
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp"); // stream de arquivos, normal
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); // decorador para salvar objetos

  oos.writeInt(12345); // tipos primitivos são serializáveis
  oos.writeObject("Today"); // Strings também
  oos.writeObject(new Date()); // a classe Date implementa Serializable

  oos.close();

  /* Lendo esses mesmos objetos do arquivo */
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("t.tmp");
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

  int i = ois.readInt();
  String today = (String) ois.readObject();
  Date date = (Date) ois.readObject();

  ois.close();
```

Se você deseja que suas classes também sejam capazes de se serializar, a princípio basta implementar essa interface e o Java se encarrega da "mágica". Entretanto, se por alguma razão você precisar de uma lógica própria para tratar de seus objetos, você pode fazer isso implementando na classe os métodos:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
    throws IOException;
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void readObjectNoData()
    throws ObjectStreamException;
```

Verifique a documentação do Java para mais detalhes sobre como eles funcionam.

Por fim, cabe notar que se um objeto faz referência a outro, a serialização **também** o escreve na *stream* (e qualquer outro que ele fizer referência, e assim por diante). Por isso, se você não tomar cuidado você pode acabar com um arquivo gigantesco, com objetos que você queria e outros que você não queria serializar. Um meio de informar ao Java que o campo X **não é** pra ser serializado é através do modificador `transient`. Exemplo:

```
class A implements Serializable {
    private B campoPermanente; // Será serializado
    private transient C campoTemporario; // Não será serializado, voltará como null
```

Nesse exemplo, é importante que a classe `B` também seja `Serializable`, ou o processo de serialização/de-serialização lançará uma exceção (`C` não importa se é ou não, já que a referência pra ela é `transient`).