# Implementar serializable no JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Porque implementar o serializable no managed bean do JSF?

Quando usar e não usar?

Para que serve a interface serializable?

Comment: Já fiz uma pergunta semelhante e foi bem respondeida aqui <http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35618/15862>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em resumo, a classe que herda da interface [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) significa que ela pode ser Serializada (em termos práticos, a instâcnia do objeto da classe em questão pode ser transformada em bytes e ser gravada em disco, ou enviada pela rede, ou passada por valor, etc). A interface em sí é uma `Marker Interface` a qual não define nenhum método. Ela serve basicamente como uma "flag".

**Porque beans implementam Serializable em JSF ?**

Uma view ou bean que possui um escopo de sessão, geralmente possui beans associados à ela/ele que por sua vez é associado a uma [HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). Tudo em um HttpSession precisa ser serializável, para que em casos de queda no servidor, ou qualquer outra situação em que seja necessário a persistência da sessão em disco, para recuperação da mesma ao reiniciar o server, isso garante alguns benefícios de preservação. Ou em casos mais complexos de cluster, as sessões precisam ser armazenadas em um datagrid e/ou cache ou qualquer outra estrutura que garanta a mesma sessão por todo nó.

**Serializable é obrigatorio em JSF ?**

Se sua aplicação não tem nenhuma das características citadas acima, não vejo nenhuma outra razão para utilizar Serializable.

**Serializable no ambiente Java EE ?**

Em casos de aplicações "full EE stack", ou até mesmo que utilize JPA junto com JSF, é aconselhável utilizar a interface Serializable. A interface tem seus usos também com JPA, porém os detalhes ficam fora do escopo da questão.